# Change background of navigation on change of section in single page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have to keep the background of navigation on "home" section transparent. But when viewport change on selection of other sections. the background color of the navigation get permanent black.

```
  <header class="clearfix">
    <nav>
    <a href="#fbsection1">HOME</a>
    <a href="#fbsection2">ABOUT US</a>
    <a href="#fbsection3">EVENTS</a>
    <a href="#fbsection4">CONTACT US</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

**Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/J9vff/3/)**

Comment: guys he have posted the fiddle

Comment: @PatsyIssa I tried by jquery on section change navigation get color, but it's not working. that's why here this question

Comment: What browser are you using ? I don't see any "black" in chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want the header background to change based on which section of the site the user is on, correct?

Look at the jQuery Waypoints plugin -- it allows you to dynamically set classes to elements based on scroll position. See it here: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about

OR, if you want a pure CSS solution, take a look at the following codepen:

http://cdpn.io/KftAm

You basically use a separate element for the background and use z-index to layer these things correctly. So you have the black background element with a z-index of say 1, the image with a z-index of 2, then the navigation with a z-index of 3.

The image would then need to be set to `position:relative;`

The issue with this is that you will have to be careful in setting the size of the background element to the same size of the navigation.

You simply need to set on the top image:

```
img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
```

and for the actual background:

```
.nav-bg {
    /* position and height the same as your fixed nav */
    position:fixed;
    z-index:998;
    background:#000;
}
```